# Testing Rails Elasticsearch implementation, waiting for refresh_index to finish before searching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-rails

I am having a great deal of issues with "race conditions" in my specs for Elasticsearch testing. Sometimes my tests pass, sometimes they don't, sometimes they find X number of results and sometimes they find a different number of results. This all stems from my searches being executed before ES is done indexing after new records to the DB.

I create the record, then run:
`Model.__elasticsearch__.refresh_index!` to refresh the index and then execute my search but I am getting inconsistent search results.

I can hack my way around this by adding a `sleep 3` after the `.refresh_index!` but this all seems like a terrible hack. Is there any other solution to this problem?

I am using the elasticsearch gem with rspec.

```
gem 'elasticsearch', '< 7.14'
gem 'elasticsearch-model', '7.1.1'
gem 'elasticsearch-rails', '7.1.1'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your workflow and use case exactly, you can leverage the `refresh` query parameter of the index API to make the document instantly searchable ([docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#docs-index-api-query-params))

Comment: Yes, I saw this and also think it can help me but I am unsure on how to use it within a Ruby on Rails context? Hmm doing some research on it here is an example: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails/issues/863